Why is Priscilla’s name placed before Aquila’s in Acts 18:26?
In Acts 18:26, most Bible translators place Priscilla’s name before Aquila even though the Greek has Aquila’s name first. Is there a reason for this?
18:26  οὗτός τε ἤρξατο παρρησιάζεσθαι ἐν τῇ συναγωγῇ ἀκούσαντες δὲ αὐτοῦ Ἀκύλας καὶ Πρίσκιλλα προσελάβοντο αὐτὸν καὶ ἀκριβέστερον αὐτῷ ἐξέθεντο τὴν τοῦ θεοῦ ὁδὸν

The original Greek [Textus Receptus (Stephanus 1550)] has A/P Acts 18:2 ; P/A Acts 18:18 ; A/P Acts 18:26. Then P/A Romans 16:3 and A/P Romans 16:19. It appears to me that both Luke and Paul are making a point, here. Up-voted +1.

Welcome to SE-BH, please see the Tour and the Help (below). Please also see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice.

Blue Letter Bible's Interlinear Features Help Tutorial
includes this statement:

The New Testament Strongs data for the KJV is based upon the Textus Receptus and the NASB is based upon the Nestle-Aland text.
Since the Textus Receptus is used as a basis for the KJV, NKJV, YLT, DBY, WEB, VUL, RVR60, WLC, LXX, and TR the KJV Strongs data will be used whenever a user is reading in these versions.
Likewise, since the Nestle-Aland text is used as a basis for the NLT, NIV, ESV, NASB, NET, RSV, ASV, HNV, and mGNT the NASB Strongs data will be used whenever a user is reading in these versions.

That is, there are two major Greek manuscript sources, with the Textus Receptus used by the KJV and other translations based on it, and more ancient manuscripts used by most of the newer translations.
Two word-order differences occur in Acts 18:26:

KJV:
οὗτός τε ἤρξατο παρρησιάζεσθαι ἐν τῇ συναγωγῇ ἀκούσαντες δὲ αὐτοῦ
Ἀκύλας καὶ Πρίσκιλλα
προσελάβοντο αὐτὸν καὶ ἀκριβέστερον αὐτῷ ἐξέθεντο τὴν
τοῦ θεοῦ ὁδὸν


NASB:
οὗτός τε ἤρξατο παρρησιάζεσθαι ἐν τῇ συναγωγῇ ἀκούσαντες δὲ αὐτοῦ
Πρίσκιλλα καὶ Ἀκύλας
προσελάβοντο αὐτὸν καὶ ἀκριβέστερον αὐτῷ ἐξέθεντο τὴν
ὁδὸν τοῦ θεοῦ

So, the answer to why the order is reversed in some translations is that they are preserving the original order of Greek manuscripts that themselves had a different order.
In terms of meaning or doctrine, the order makes no difference.
The real question is why this different order occurs in these ancient manuscripts.

+1 So the real question becomes why did earlier manuscripts list Priscilla first.. and did later editors change the text because they didn't Paul  to accept that a woman had priority over her husband in one of his letters. I have to disagree that it makes no difference. Some sill argue today that a woman cannot lead.
